# How can I make the Maven plugin include only the necessary dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm using the maven-jar-plugin to build a jar file with the option `<includes>`. This means the jar should contain only some of the packages. But the .jar contains pom.xml with all its dependencies. How can I make Maven include only the necessary dependencies?

Comment: No sure to understand correctly: you want to filter dependencies based on the included (filtered) packages of your application (packaged in the jar)?

Comment: remove the unused dependencies from your pom file? Usually building a jar with includes/excludes sounds wrong...

Comment: If so make separate maven projects which contains the different packages and then you can define different dependencies in the appropriate pom file...

Answer (score -1):

Maven includes by default all the dependencies that are needed for a successful compilation and pack them for them in fianl jar. 
If you want to exclude certain dependencies (since they will be supplied in runtime, etc.), set the dependency's `<scope>` property to`<scope>provided</scope>`.